# how to pass index to php function for pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I have loop in my index.php :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $sent+1; $i++)  {

    $eintrag = "INSERT INTO users_match (user_id,match_id) VALUES ('$live_editor[$i]','$match[$i]')";
    $eintragen = mysql_query($eintrag);
    $eintragen = $storage_access->eintrag($live_editor[$i], $match[$i]);
```

I am moving this query to external file and calling with PDO function:

```
public function eintrag($live_editor[$i], $match[$i])
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO users_match (user_id,match_id) VALUES (:live_editor,:match) ";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute([
        ':live_editor' => $live_editor[$i],
        ':match' => $match[$i],
    ]);
    return $statement->fetchObject();
}
```

and calling in index.php :

```
$eintragen = $storage_access->eintrag($live_editor[$i], $match[$i]);
```

I am not that good in php, but how to pass index values as the function parameter? When I do like this I get error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: Dont mix `mysql_` and `mysqli_` or `PDO` all in he same script. Which one do you use to make a connection??

Comment: @RiggsFolly I use PDO

Comment: Whats this then `$eintragen = mysql_query($eintrag);`

Comment: Oh I get what you are doing now, silly me

Comment: I dont think you want `return $statement->fetchObject();` at the end of your new function. You are doing an INSERT and therefore there will be nothing to return

Comment: You need to concatenate variables and not just put them into the string: `VALUES ('" . $live_editor[$i] . "',` but you should look into prepared statements tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function parameters aren't correct.

Instead of:

```
public function eintrag($live_editor[$i], $match[$i])
```

You should have:

```
public function eintrag($live_editor_item, $match_item)
```

and in your function do:

```
$statement->execute([
        ':live_editor' => $live_editor_item,
        ':match' => $match_item,
    ]);
```

you function call will still be:

```
$eintragen = $storage_access->eintrag($live_editor[$i], $match[$i]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The function does not need indexed parameters, only variable names.

```
public function eintrag($live_editor, $match)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO users_match (user_id,match_id) VALUES (:live_editor,:match) ";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute([
        ':live_editor' => $live_editor,
        ':match' => $match,
    ]);
    return $statement->fetchObject();
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650427/how-to-pass-index-to-php-function-for-pdo#comment60895016_36650427